# How do I use vba to make a new button in Powerpoint and how do I make a progress bar after I click on it?

Tags: vba, button, progress-bar, toolbar, slideshow

I have some code that I execute when a slide show presentation begins but because it takes some time, I want to create a button in a Powerpoint toolbar to execute this code.

So, I click on the button and after that I want to happear a progress bar!

How can I use vba to create a new button in a Powerpoint toolbar and how can I make a progress bar when I click on it?

Oh, at the end of the progress bar I want to execute the slide show.
How can I do that as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

> How can I use vba to create a new
>   button in a Powerpoint toolbar

Try this code:

```
Sub AddButton()
   Dim cb As CommandBar

   Set cb = Application.CommandBars.Add("additional_toolbar", msoBarTop, , True)

   With cb.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
      .Caption = "click me"
      .OnAction = "macro_name"
      .Style = msoButtonCaption
   End With
   cb.Visible = True
End Sub
```

2.

> how can I make a progress bar when I
>   click on it?

I would suggest creating UserForm with ProgressBar control on it.

3.

try this to begin slide show [[source]](http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/launch_ppt_presenter_view.html):

```
Sub BeginSlideShow()
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run
End Sub
```

Additionally:
there is no equivalent of PERSONAL (from Excel) in PowerPoint , only place for storing code is presentation itself, so you need open presentation before executing any code.

Comment: thanks m8. one last question, how can I put an icon on the button?

Comment: to create button with picture you need to switch its style to msoButtonIconAndCaption (check this - http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showpost.php?p=278876&postcount=9) and to point to the icon from Office you have to use FaceId = /number/ you can find numbers (and pictures) in attachment to this post - http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showpost.php?p=200517&postcount=2